# Keep receiving the same two errors: illegal and parsing error

Tags: java

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong at this point. I've been getting the same two errors:

> CoffeeBot.java:79: illegal start of expression
>
> }
>
> CoffeeBot.java:82: reached end of file while parsing
>
> } //public class
>
> 2 errors

Someone correct me thanks?

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class CoffeeBot {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int n1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int n2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

      for (int i = 0;i<args.length;i++) // REMEMBER TO PUT IN ARGS LENGTH

      if (!(n1 > 0) && !(n2 > 0)) { // This is for both negative inputs n1 and n2

        System.out.println("Negative supply chain. System terminating.");

        return;

      }

      if (n1 < 0) { // This is for negative input n1

        System.out.println("Negative supply of coffee cups. System terminating.");

          return;

      }

      if (n2 < 0) { // This is for negative input n2

        System.out.println("Negative supply of coffee shots. System terminating.");

          return;

      }

      else {// If inputs comply with rules then proceed to here

        System.out.println("Hello, what's your name?");

        String name;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

          name = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Would you like to order some coffee, " + name + "? (y/n)");

        String yesno;

          yesno = keyboard.next();

          if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

              System.out.println("Great! Let's get started.");

              System.out.println(" ");

              System.out.println("Order selection");

              System.out.println("---------------");

              System.out.println(" ");

          }

          if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

              System.out.println("Come back next time, " + name +".");

                return;
          }

          else {

              System.out.println("Invalid response. Try again.");

                while (yesno.toIgnoreCase("n"))
                while (yesno.toIgnoreCase("y"))
          }

        }//else

     } //main args

} //public class
```

Comment: `while (yesno.toIgnoreCase("n"))` and `while (yesno.toIgnoreCase("y"))` are formatted incorrectly

Comment: Not relevant, but you should learn how to properly format your code ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

`yesno` is of type `String`.

```
 while (yesno.toIgnoreCase("n"))
 while (yesno.toIgnoreCase("y"))
```

there is no `toIgnoreCase()` method , i guess you meant `equalsIgnoreCase()`.also put `;` after the 2nd while loop better  yet use `{}` all the time.

Comment: Doing that might make the code compile, but those two likes are still so very wrong, that it hurts.